# JSON: Providing Constant Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Though I'm using iOS, I don't think that's relevant here.

I need to be able to use a constant in two of the values for JSON.  Reason:  We're using different servers for Development and Production, and can't have the development data mixed with production Data. At build time we'll provide values based on the environment settings (development / production).

Thus, how can I use a constant value for "rsids" and server" in the JSON below:

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "analytics" : {
        "rsids" : "//I would like to put a Constant Here",
        "server" : "",
        "charset" : "UTF-8",
        "ssl" : false,
        "offlineEnabled" : true,
        "lifecycleTimeout" : 300,
        "privacyDefault" : "optedin",
        "poi" : []
    },
    "target" : {
        "clientCode" : "",
        "timeout" : 5
    },
    "audienceManager" : {
        "server" : "//I would like to put a Constant Here"
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
NSStirng const *kServerURL = @"www.google.com"

"audienceManager" : {
        "server" : kServerUrl
    }
```

**UPDATE**

There is no Dictionary. I'm using the iOS SDK by Adobe for Site Catalyst. They have a JSON file that I have to edit and provide RSID and Server values. The JSON that you see in the question is the entire file.

The SDK has a library file (.a) also. Here are the docs: http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/mobile/ios/index.html#ADBMobile_Class_and_Method_Reference

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to _send_ a constant value in the JSON or use a constant value _received_ in the JSON at runtime?

Comment: send a constant value in the JSON.

Comment: Basically, the value of the constant will change at build time.

Comment: I need the ability to change the value of the constant at build time.

Comment: How are you encoding the JSON? With NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: I'm using the iOS SDK by Adobe for Site Catalyst. They have a JSON file that I have to edit and provide RSID and Server values.  The JSON that you see in the question is the entire file.

Comment: You'll have to create multiple files if you want different values. You can't have a JSON file be dynamic as you're looking for.

Comment: Show how you are creating your dictionary.

Comment: After you read the JSON file and deserialize it, do `[jsonDict setValue:theConstant forKeyPath:@"analytics.rsids"];` and `[jsonDict setValue:theOtherConstant forKeyPath:@"audienceManager.server"];`.  (Be sure to use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option on the `JSONObjectWithData` call.)

Comment: But this would be done at run time.  Do you think I should run script for compile time?

Comment: And, of course another approach is to put in something like `"$$PLACEHOLDER1$$"` in place of the need-to-be changed values, and then do a simple text replacement on those on the JSON file, using something like `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the value of the constant *at build time* you should be using #if/#ifdef and friends to do so.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSString const *kServerURL = @"www.google.com"
#else
NSString const *kServerURL = @"www.bing.com"
#endif
```

Comment: This is exactly what we are doing; however, I can't figure out how to get the JSON file (posted in the question) to recognize the constants.

Comment: @user1107173, how are you creating the dictionary that you are serializing?

Comment: There is no Dictionary.  I'm using the iOS SDK by Adobe for Site Catalyst. They have a JSON file that I have to edit and provide RSID and Server values. The JSON that you see in the question is the entire file.  The SDK has a library file (.a) also.  Here are the docs: http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/mobile/ios/index.html#ADBMobile_Class_and_Method_Reference

Comment: I need the ability to change the value of the constant at build time.

Comment: @user1107173 - You need to change the constant *before* you build the JSON file.  And then somehow incorporate that constant into the building of the JSON file.  The other option is to modify the deserialized JSON after you read the file.

Comment: @HotLicks  Thanks!  Any advice how I can build the JSON file at build time?

Comment: @HotLicks  The SDK will look for a file called ADBMobileConfig.json for configuration.

Comment: @user1107173 - I'm not a build guru.  But see my comment above for a "cheater" technique.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create multiple files then. You can't have a JSON file be dynamic.

When creating your files from code, you can use constants. At the top of your .m file before the @implementation portion, defined them on multiple lines. One for development, one for QA, and one for production. Comment out the two you don't want and leave the one you do want. When using it, use the format.

```
"server":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",kServerUrl];
```

It is often a good idea to have a dummy login that can safely communicate with your servers. Such a login would have an example set of data to be read, and any uploads would be ignored. This is handy for testing between the different environments, including production, and allows any apps submitted to the App Store to be fully tested with a valid login.